# How To Add Space Between Two Inline-Block Elements (Screenshot Included)?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a web page responsive, however when the screen resolution is 1282 x 630, this is what I'm getting with these two inline-block elements:

[image]

As you can see, the elements are both glued together. I would like to add a space between them to seperate them.

Here is my HTML :

```css
.links {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 85%;
}

.links div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 430px;
}

.shop {
  background: url("images/shopCover.jpeg") no-repeat top center;
}

.journal {
  background: url("images/journalCover.jpeg") no-repeat top center;
}

.links div h2 {
  padding-top: 170px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section class="links">

  <a href="productPage.php">
    <div class="shop">
      <h2>Shop</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="blog/cms.php">
    <div class="journal">
      <h2>Journal</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

</section>
```

How do I do this?

I appreciate all responses.

Comment: Maybe you can turn your code into a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), this way it is easier for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Are you speaking about <br>?

Comment: How about `div.shop {margin-right: 2px;}`?

Comment: Just a note: Your HTML is not valid.

Comment: @reporter weird, that's what I put but it still doesnt want to work

Comment: Can decrease your width to 49%, it can also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `margin` to `.links div`

```css
.links {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 85%;
}

.links div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 430px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.shop {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg") no-repeat top center;
}

.journal {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg") no-repeat top center;
}

.links div h2 {
  padding-top: 170px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<section class="links">

  <a href="productPage.php">
    <div class="shop">
      <h2>Shop</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="blog/cms.php">
    <div class="journal">
      <h2>Journal</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

</section>
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a space between the two inline-block elements, not at the bottom. I tried using margin-right: 2px but it still doesn't want to work

Comment: Oh wait a minute, my media query wasn't properly coded...I added the margin and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex instead, As inline-block have default margin.

```css
   

  *
    {
      box-sizing:border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .links {
      padding-bottom: 30px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 85%;
      display: flex;
    }
    .links div 
   {
      width: 50%;
      box-shadow: 6px 0px 0px #fff;
      height: 430px;
      margin-bottom: 25px;
      margin-left:10px
    }
    .links div:first-child 
    {
      margin-left:0;
    }
    .shop {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    }

    .journal {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg") no-repeat top center;
    }

    .links div h2 {
      padding-top: 170px;
      font-size: 32px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<section class="links">

    <div class="shop">
  <a href="productPage.php">
      <h2>Shop</h2>
  </a>
    </div>
    <div class="journal">
  <a href="blog/cms.php">
      <h2>Journal</h2>
  </a>
    </div>
</section>
```